# Counting of rows (with conditions) after particular value (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below:

```
group    sequence   action     value1       value2      value3
1        1          special    1            0           1
1        2          special    1            1           0
1        3          special    1            0           1
1        4          act1       1            0           NULL
1        5          act1       1            0           NULL
1        6          act2       1            0           NULL
1        7          special    1            1           1
1        8          act1       1            1           NULL
1        9          act2       1            1           NULL
1       10          special    1            0           1
1       11          act1       1            0           NULL
2        1          special    1            1           1
2        2          act1       1            1           NULL
```

I need to count general number of actions: "act1" and "act2" which take place after action "special" (column "group" in this issue is not important for me)

So, at the end I would like to get table like this:

```
action    value1     value2     value3     count_act1     count_act2 
special   1          0          1          3              1
special   1          1          0          0              0
special   1          1          1          2              1
```

Is there any window function, which can help me?

Comment: I don't follow the question.  Where did the `NULL`s in `value3` go?

Comment: Can you have in your sequence of the same group something like special, special, act1, special, act1, ...  OR actx in the same group are always after special?

Comment: in terms of actions "act1" and "act2" we don't look at columns "value1", "value2", and "value3" (values in this columns can be different compared with action "special" - we only look at values in columns "valueX" when it comes to action "special"  ).                                                                                  
We only want to know how many times appeared actions "act1" and "act2" after action "special"

Comment: sequence is a "true" sequence number inside "group"?

Comment: @etsa answer on your first questions: yes :)

Comment: @etsa in terms of your second question: no, because sequence is connected with every row in my table, and I show you my table with conditions, so for example sequence for "special" is 1 and sequence for act1 can be 48, but always sequence of "act1" (or "act2") will be greater than sequence of "special".

Comment: action "act1" can take place only after action "special" and action "act2" can take place only after action "act1"

Comment: I am a bit confused (maybe my fault) by your second answer as regard your first: [always sequence of "act1" (or "act2") will be greater than sequence of "special"]: now it seems to me you can't have in the SAME GROUP 1 special, 2 act1, 3 special, 4 special, 5 act2?  Can you do a more exaustive sampe data or confirm this?

Comment: i'm sorry, it can be confused. So: a) we don't look at values in columns value1, value2 and value3 for action: "act1" and "act2" b) (your example: 1 special, 2 act2, 3 special, 4 special, 5 act2) this is not possible, because act2 can take place only after act1 <- for example you can only click on "play" after choosing movie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this (if it works for you we can go on to optimize it, but I'm not sure it covers all your cases)?

```
SELECT X.*
, COALESCE(RC_ACT1, 0) AS RC_ACT1
, COALESCE(RC_ACT2, 0) AS RC_ACT2
FROM MYTABLE X
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A.GROUP_, A.SEQUENCE, COUNT(B.ACT1) AS RC_ACT1  
    FROM (
        SELECT * ,LEAD(ACTION) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ ORDER BY SEQUENCE) AS SUCC1
        FROM MYTABLE 
        WHERE ACTION='special'
        ) A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ACTION  AS ACT1, GROUP_, SEQUENCE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ACTION = 'act1') B ON B.GROUP_=A.GROUP_ AND B.SEQUENCE > A.SEQUENCE  
    WHERE SUCC1 IS NULL 
    GROUP BY A.GROUP_, A.SEQUENCE
    ) Y ON X.GROUP_= Y.GROUP_ AND X.SEQUENCE=Y.SEQUENCE
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A.GROUP_, A.SEQUENCE, COUNT(B.ACT1) AS RC_ACT2  
    FROM (
        SELECT * ,LEAD(ACTION) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ ORDER BY SEQUENCE) AS SUCC1
        FROM MYTABLE 
        WHERE ACTION='special'
        ) A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ACTION  AS ACT1, GROUP_, SEQUENCE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ACTION = 'act2') B ON B.GROUP_=A.GROUP_ AND B.SEQUENCE > A.SEQUENCE  
    WHERE SUCC1 IS NULL 
    GROUP BY A.GROUP_, A.SEQUENCE
    ) Z ON X.GROUP_= Z.GROUP_ AND X.SEQUENCE=Z.SEQUENCE
WHERE X.ACTION = 'special';
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| group_ | sequence | action  | value1 | value2 | value3 | rc_act1 | rc_act2 |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
|      1 |        1 | special |      1 |      0 |      1 |       0 |       0 |
|      1 |        2 | special |      1 |      1 |      0 |       0 |       0 |
|      1 |        3 | special |      1 |      0 |      1 |       2 |       1 |
|      2 |        1 | special |      1 |      1 |      1 |       1 |       0 |
+--------+----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: at the first glance everything is ok! :) but I need one hour to check your solution in details. I'll come back to you asap :) thanks!

Comment: There is one problem - I look at my data and in one group we can change several times values in columns "valueX" and we have to distinguish "act1" and "act2" after every action "special" in this group. Ehh its difficult case..... But thanks! thanks to you I look at the data from the different side :)

Comment: hmm... and I dont understand this:   SELECT * ,LEAD(ACTION) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ ORDER BY SEQUENCE) AS SUCC1
        FROM MYTABLE 
        WHERE ACTION='special'   - I know functions lag/lead but if we use 'where action = 'special' ' every value of succ1 will be 'special' too ?

Comment: no (I used it during "exploring" the problem, but I left to find the last special before "act").  You can try it executing one of the inner query alone.  At the moment (it can be more clean) you could change it with a ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ ORDER BY SEQUENCE DESC) AS RN1 and changing WHERE SUCC1 iS NULL with WHERE RN1 = 1

Comment: yes, now I see it, but unfortunately it not solve a problem with fact, that in one group we can have several times changed values in columns "valueX" and we have to distinguish "act1" and "act2" after every action "special" in one group. If I understand your query correctly, we take into account the last variant of parameters for action "special" ? and we count only actions "act1" and "act2" which appeared after this last variant?

Comment: that's was what you asked for.  Post new sample data and change the original question.

Comment: yes, you're right - I didn't take into an account all options. now the sample data is changed

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your help (its my first time on slack), I'll open new topic:)

Comment: And remember to consider to vote for an answer if it helped you (pls visit stack intro tour).